# Toast doesnt work with Loading in Ionic2?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, typescript2.0

So I make an http call. Before http call Loading is presented and when response comes (success or error) the loading is dismissed and Toast is displayed. Toast should last for 3 seconds, but that is not the case and it gets shown for .5 second. And only 1 time per page load.

**How can I show Loading during HTTP call and how can I show toast after Loading is dismissed so it works??**

Here is HTTP call

```
    this.presentLoading();
    this.http.post(this.mainUrl + '/api/v1/filters', obj, {headers: headers}).subscribe(data => {
      this.loader.dismiss();
      this.presentToast(data.json().success_message, 3000, "toast-success");
    }, err => {
      this.loader.dismiss();
      this.presentToast(err.json().error_message, 3000, "toast-error");
    });
```

presentToast function

```
presentToast(msg, duration, cssClass) {
    let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
      message: msg,
      duration: duration,
      position: 'bottom',
      dismissOnPageChange: true,
      cssClass: cssClass
    });

    toast.onDidDismiss(() => {
      // Do something
    });

    toast.present();
  }
```

presentLoading

```
presentLoading() {
    this.loader = this.loadingCtrl.create({
      content: 'Please wait...'
    });

    this.loader.dismiss().then(()=>{

    });

    this.loader.present();
  }
```

Defining loader

```
 ...
 export class Filter {

  public loader = this.loadingCtrl.create({
    content: "Please wait.."
  });
  ...
```